# Is it possible to run a script which loops through hosts with rsh/ssh

Tags: linux, bash, csh

I have tried to run following csh script which ssh to all computers on our network with the purpose of yum installing software passed as arguments.  However, the script fails to continue once I have rsh to another host. Is there a way around this problem?

```
if ($1 == "")then
    echo -n "Please enter a package to install\n"
    set package=$<
else set package = $#argv
endif

set numlines = `cat $NM_HOME/sh_local/nc_network2.txt | grep -v "^#" | fgrep "%" |  wc -l`
while ($numlines>0)
    set line = `cat $NM_HOME/sh_local/nc_network2.txt | grep -v "^#" | fgrep "%" | tail -$numlines | head -1`
    set host2 = `echo $line | cut -f 1 -d %`
    set where = `echo $line | cut -f 2 -d %`
    if ($host2 == $this_machine) then 
    echo "This is $host2....skipping rsh to this machine"
    echo ""
    goto yum
    endif
    echo ""
    echo "logging into $host2 $where"
    echo ""
    sleep 1
    rsh $host2
    yum:
    echo ""
    echo "Preparing to install $package on $host2"
    sudo yum -y install $package
    if ($host2 == $this_machine) then 
    goto decrement
    else
    logout
    goto decrement
    endif

    decrement:
    @ numlines--

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ssh`/`rsh`-ing to another host does not magically continue the execution of your script on that host. Executing `ssh hostname` in a script has the exact same effect as executing `ssh hostname` in your shell — it connects to that machine, runs an interactive shell there, and leaves you in that shell. Your script execution will only continue after you close the `ssh`/`rsh` connection yourself.

In order to perform some action on that host, you need to provide an explicit command you want to run on that host, like this:

`rsh $host2 sudo yum -y install $package`

Note that this is only a naive example for illustration purposes; it likely won't be enough to fix the entire logic of your script, but should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm almost there. The only issue I have now is that I must logout of interactive shell once the yum install is complete. Is there a rsh $host2 sudo yum -y install $package; logout type command?

Comment: `man rsh` on Mac (which is BSD `rsh`) states that `rsh normally terminates when the remote command does.` On my Ubuntu box, `rsh` is a symlink to `ssh`, and `ssh` also does terminate when the remote command is done, but the manual does not say anything specific about `rsh` behavior, and I don't have an `rsh` server set up, so I cannot test.

Answer (score 1):

**YES**. My answer is provided below only by reading your "Question" and not what you have put up in the code that you posted.

I have been doing this for many years as below.

- create a list of hosts with onehost on each line.
- enable SSH key based authentication upfront. This can be done manually but I had done it in the past using `perl` and `expect`.
- run a `for` loop as below to perform action onall the servers:

  for i in `cat hosts_list`; do  ssh $i dmidecode  | grep -m 1 'Serial Number:'; done

Above oneliner will give me the serial numbers of all the servers wic are mentioned in the `host_list`. This a shot example of pulling serial number. however, you can write a full fledged bash script following the exact same logic.

for more advanced requirement, consider using `perl` and the `ssh` modules that are available on `CPAN`